# Is there a dumbed down version of the open mapping theorem for finite dimensional real vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, topological-vector-spaces

I would like to understand why any surjective linear transformation between finite dimensional topological real vector spaces, each with the natural topology, is in fact an open map.

Reading around, I think this follows as a special case of the open mapping theorem from functional analysis. However, the theorems I've found, namely Theorem 2.11 in Rudin's Functional Analysis and Theorem 11.4 in Kelley & Namioka, are a little over my head at this point.

Is there a less general version of the proof specifically for finite dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces? I have a fair understanding of general topology, real-analysis, and linear algebra, but not so much functional analysis. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would post this as a comment, since I need to check it a little more before I am totally ok with it--alas, it is too long. So, an answer it shall stay.

EDIT: I should emphasize that where I am using finite dimesionality is that every linear map in sight is continuous. In particular, a linear isomorphism is a homeomorphism.

I think this should suffice. Let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional real vector spaces and $T:V\to W$ a surjective linear map.

EDIT EDIT: As Matt E points out below, it is prudent to mention the following. Below I prove that the map $\pi$ is open when we give $V/Y$ the quotient topology, but not that it is open when we give it the standard metric topology which makes $\widetilde{T}$ a homeomorphism. But, the fact that the quotient topology on $V/Y$ coincides with the linear topology is deducible because of the following: a) we're in finite dimensions so $Y$ is closed, and b) give $V$ you're favorite norm, since $Y$ is closed it's ommonly known then that the quotient topology on $V/Y$ is the topology induced by the quotient norm and so the quotient topology is the linear topology (all normed topologies are the same in finite dimensions). There are other ways to see that the two topologies coincide if you're interested. :)

We first claim that the projection map $V\to V/Y$ is open for any $Y$ a subspace of $V$. To see this, we note that it suffices to prove that $\pi^{-1}(\pi(U))$ (where $\pi$ is the projection map) is open for each open set $U$ in $V$. But, note that $$\pi^{-1}(\pi(U))=\bigcup_{v\in Y}(v+U)$$

which, being the union of open sets, is open.

Now that we have the projection map is open this should be easy. Namely, let $Y=\ker T$. We know then that $T$ induces a linear isomorphism $\widetilde{T}:V/Y\to W$. Since this is a linear isomorphism, it is, in particular, a homeomorphism and so an open map. So, if we take $U\subseteq V$ open we have that $T(U)$ is just $\widetilde{T}(\pi(U))$ where $\pi$ is the projection $V\to V/Y$. So, we see that $\pi(U)$ is open in $V/Y$ since $\pi$ is an open map, and $\widetilde{T}(\pi(U))$ is open because $\widetilde{T}$ is a homeomorphism. So, $T(U)=\widetilde{T}(\pi(U))$ is open as desired.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I think I understand everything in your last paragraph. However, I don't get how you proved the projection $V\to V/Y$ is open. Why does it suffice to show $T^{-1}(T(U))$ is open, and why does the equality $$T^{-1}(T(U))=\bigcup_{v\in\ker Y}(v+U)$$ hold? Is $T^{-1}(T(U))\subset V$, but $\bigcup (v+U)\subset V/U$?

Comment: @NoomiHolloway I made a typo--see if it makes more sense now that I've edited.

Comment: Thanks! Should the union be over $v\in\ker\pi$? If so, I understand the equality. Do you mind explaining why it suffices to show $\pi^{-1}(\pi(U))$ is open for each open $U$ in $V$ to prove $\pi\colon V\to V/Y$ is open?

Comment: @Noomi: Dear Alex and Noomi, The definition of $\pi$ being open is that $\pi(U)$ is open.  So the claim being made is (equivalent to the claim) that a subset of $V/Y$ is open iff its preimage in $V$ is open, or equivalently, that $V/Y$ is equipped with quotient topology induced by regarding it as a quotient of $V$.  This is true; to see it, it might be easiest to choose a basis for $V$ extending a basis for $Y$, so that $V$ can be regarded as the product of $Y$ and $V/Y$.  Regards,

Comment: @MattE Thanks for that input! While I see how the approach you mention works, I am confused whether or not you are saying that I made a mistake.

Comment: @NoomiHolloway It should have been unioning over $\ker\pi$ which is $Y$. This suffices because, as Matt E points out, by definition, a subset of $V/Y$ is open if and only if its preimage is open.

Comment: @Alex: Dear Alex, I am not saying that you made a mistake, but rather that your argument is incomplete.  To show that $\pi$ is open, literally you have to show that $\pi(U)$ is open in $V/Y$ for $U$ open in $V$.  You claim that it suffices to check that $\pi^{-1}(\pi(U))$ is open, which is true, but requires justification.  (It's not true for an arbitrary map $\pi$, but uses the fact that this particular $\pi$ is a quotient map.)  Of course the justification is not hard, but then neither is the original openness statement --- so given that one is giving a careful proof of that, it seems to ...

Comment: make sense to give a careful proof of the quotient topology statement as well.  (I note that in your most recent comment you say that "by definition" a subset of $V/Y$ is open if and only if its preimage is open.  This is probably *not* the usual definition of the topology on $V/Y$; rather, one would choose an isomorphism of $V/Y$ with $\mathbb R^n$ and use this to transport the topology of $\mathbb R^n$ to $V/Y$ (then check this is indepdenent of the choice).  Checking that $V \to V/Y$ is a topological quotient is then something that has to be checked (although the check is very ...

Comment: ... straigthforward).  Apologies if you think I'm being too pedantic!  Best wishes,

Comment: @MattE Oh, ok, I think I understand. So you were just saying that I should mention that the normal topology we want to put on $V/Y$ as a fin. dim. vector space coincides with the quotient topology. I assumed that this would have been known to the OP--the subspace is closed since we're in finite dimensions, and quotient spaces by closed subspaces have their topologies given by a norm. See my edits. Please let me know if I am understanding you correctly :) Thanks!

Comment: Dear Alex, Exactly!  And, as your nice explanation shows, there are lots of ways to see this.  Best wishes,

Comment: @MattE, Alex, thanks! I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 7):

Any finite-dimensional (edit: Hausdorff) topological real vector space has the usual Euclidean topology (exercise), and any surjective linear transformation between finite-dimensional topological real vector spaces is isomorphic to projection to some subset of coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (exercise), so this follows from the fact that any projection of an open Euclidean ball is a (possibly lower-dimensional) open Euclidean ball.